# Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 jQuery 0x800200003 Javascript runtime error: Member not found

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, runtime-error

When I debug using Internet Explorer 10 I get the following error, which also highlights line 2582 of jquery-1.9.1.js. This error does not occur when I debug in Chrome.

Under Open Exception Settings I unchecked all of the Thrown and User-handled options but this issue persists.

Any ideas how to prevent this error from occurring?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post your code which triggers this code?

Comment: I also started to get this error yesterday, out of the blue, with no changes that I can think of to my code. When I run the app from the server, it works fine, no errors. I also checked the JavaScript console, and there are no reported errors. The app I'm working on is an MVC 4.0 project. Win 7 Pro.

Comment: My error went away the next day. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

It is compatibility view.  Make sure you're NOT running compatibility view in your IE browser.